# What did Theophilus mean in book I, chapter 14 of Theophilus to Autolycus when speaking to "unbelievers and despisers"?

Tags: ancient-greek

I am comparing translations from Rick Rogers and Rev. Marcus Dods. In the second to the last sentence of chapter 14 Rogers translates a Greek word as "homosexual acts." Dobs, on the other hand, translates the same Greek word as "filthiness."

I am not a translator of Greek nor do I have the original text of Theophilus's three books. I have not been able to find the original text. I have participated in a [WikiTalk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Homosexuality%20and%20Roman%20Catholicism#Church%20Fathers) discussion on this differing of translations. Rick Rogers, Theophilus of Antioch (Lexington Books 2000ISBN 978-0-73910132-2), p. 59. Ante-Nicene Fathers, Vol. 2, Theophilus to Autolycus, Book 1, Chapter XIV, p. 93. Dobs translation in the second to the last sentence in Chapter 14 for the Greek word is "filthiness", whereas, Rogers translates the same Greek word as "homosexual acts." I am looking for the correct translation of this Greek word (forgive my lack of presenting this Greek word). In Chapter 1, Theophilus (according to Dobs) speaks to "... whether you do not corrupt boys, ..." My participation in the WikiTalk went like this:

> All documentation
> that I presented was Catholic in origin except one (and I'm not sure
> that it isn't.) I began this effort seeking assistance because I have no
> knowledge of the wiki process. I merely set forth reasonable
> documentation that could be used. Very interesting, interesting
> enough to warrant some form of correction to Rogers' translation.
> His interpretation comes to hi:When I read your comment, I
> presumed that I had mistyped, but I find I did not. The Greek text is
> in column 1045, what is in column 1046 is the Migne translation into
> Latin (not "my" Latin translation - I wasn't born then), which has no
> more authority than the English translations. The Greek text does
> have the word ἀρσενοκοιτἰα (in the dative plural case): ἐπὰν
> ἐμφύρωνται μοιχείαις, καὶ πορνείας, καὶ ἀρσενοκοιτίαις ... The same
> document has not only the abstract noun ἀρσενοκοιτἰα (literally,
> male-lying): it also the concrete noun denoting the doer:
> ἀρσενοκοίτης (literally, male-lier - or should I spell it male-lyer?) in
> col. 1028B, where it says such people will not see God unless they
> first cleanse themselves of all filthiness (μολυσμός). You do realize,
> don't you, that Greek dictionaries indicate that the two words
> ἀρσενοκοιτἰα and ἀρσενοκοίτης do refer to homosexual activity?
> Esoglou (talk) 14:41, 16 April 2014 (UTC)

---

> not from a translation
> but from the invention of a series of terms; "filthiness," 'luxuria,'
> sodomy and homosexual acts. My documentation validates what the
> Church teaches using ancient text from Gregory the Great,
> Augustine as well as the use of scripture. As with all wikis, there are
> embedded links that could deal with the above documentation. To
> leave Rogers' translation as is misleads others to believe that
> homosexuality was indeed the issue of the Early Church Fathers.
> That is not acceptable.
> AlaskaTW — Preceding undated comment
> added 03:36, 15 April 2014 (UTC)

---

> I have been away, and the thought of having to read all the above
> about English words such as "filthiness" daunts me. May I be
> excused? Autolycus wrote in Greek, not English, and the word he
> used (see PL6, col. 1045C) was ἀρσενοκοιτία (arsenokoitia). This
> word literally means male-lying. If you look up a dictionary of
> Greek, ancient or modern, you will be told it means (male)
> homosexual intercourse. Since one fairly ancient Greek writer says
> men can commit ἀρσενοκοιτία even with their wives, in that context
> it must mean anal intercourse, as stated by John Boswell ((Boswell,
> John (1981). Christianity, social tolerance, and homosexuality: gay
> people in Western Europe from the beginning of the Christian era to
> the fourteenth century. University of Chicago Press. ISBN 978-0-
> 226-06711-7.).
>
> The explanation that User:Roscelese gave at 01:03, 14 April 2014
> of the choice by 19th-century Dods of the English word "filthiness"
> to represent ἀρσενοκοιτία in his translation of the passage is
> obviously correct.
>
> As an aside, the Latin translation of ἀρσενοκοιτία given in PG6 as
> puerorum stuprum (literally, rape of boys) throws light on the use of
> the Latin phrase stupratores puerorum (literally, rapers of boys) by
> the early 4th-century Council of Elvira.
> Esoglou (talk) 18:50, 15
> April 2014 (UTC)

---

> Thanks, Esoglou. Thanks for your effort and the link to the original
> language of Theophilus to Autolycus. I believe you meant to link to
> 1046C, not 1045 C. No problem as I believe that I am well on the
> path to discover the original intent. Although, I do not see the Greek
> usage, "ἀρσενοκοιτία (arsenokoitia) in the text. Your contribution is
> very interesting. Your Latin translation, I believe represents the true
> concern of the Early Church Fathers; "ἀρσενοκοιτία (arsenokoitia)."
> Again, my concern that Rogers' translation misleads readers into
> believing that the issue the Early Church Fathers had was
> homosexuality. At the very least, this quote should be removed. I
> will continue my research. Thanks.
> 63.140.83.85 (talk) 23:18, 15
> April 2014 (UTC)AlaskaTW

---

> When I read your comment, I presumed that I had mistyped, but I
> find I did not. The Greek text is in column 1045, what is in column
> 1046 is the Migne translation into Latin (not "my" Latin translation -
> I wasn't born then), which has no more authority than the English
> translations. The Greek text does have the word ἀρσενοκοιτἰα (in the
> dative plural case): ἐπὰν ἐμφύρωνται μοιχείαις, καὶ πορνείας, καὶ
> ἀρσενοκοιτίαις ... The same document has not only the abstract noun
> ἀρσενοκοιτἰα (literally, male-lying): it also the concrete noun
> denoting the doer: ἀρσενοκοίτης (literally, male-lier - or should I
> spell it male-lyer?) in col. 1028B, where it says such people will not
> see God unless they first cleanse themselves of all filthiness
> (μολυσμός). You do realize, don't you, that Greek dictionaries
> indicate that the two words ἀρσενοκοιτἰα and ἀρσενοκοίτης do refer
> to homosexual activity? Esoglou (talk) 14:41, 16 April 2014 (UTC)

---

> Esoglou, this is the text that I believe we are both addressing:
> “Incredulis autem et superbis, et iis qui non acquiescunt veritati,
> credunt  autem iniquitati, cum repleti fuerint adulteriis,
> scortationibus, puerorum stupris, avaritia et infandis simulacrorum
> cultibus, erit ira et indignatio, tribulatio et angustiae10, ac tandem
> tales ignis aeternus 347 detinebit."
> The word that is in question, I believe is, "scortationibus." Please
> correct me if I am wrong. Your statement, "where it says such people
> will not see God unless they first cleanse themselves of all filthiness
> (μολυσμός)," tells me that Dods' translation using "filthiness" is not
> an incorrect translation of the Greek word but his sentence structure
> may be wrong. If the two Greek words, "ἀρσενοκοιτἰα and
> ἀρσενοκοίτης" refer to "(literally, rape of boys)," "ἀρσενοκοιτία
> given in PG6 as puerorum stuprum," then the issue was not
> homosexuality but instead pedophilia. One can play on the words
> homosexual and pedophilia and divert the attention from pedophilia
> but then that would mislead the intent of the sentence. I'm beginning
> to get a better feel for the intent of the sentence as opposed to the
> intent of Rogers' use of "homosexual acts." This is very helpful. The
> argument is becoming very clear and I will be more adept at
> discussing this text when an acquaintance comes back with his
> translation, interpretation. (talk) 19:25, 16 April 2014
> (UTC)Alaska (talk) 19:25, 16 April 2014 (UTC)

---

> While it's clear that recent translations of early Christian texts do often impose modern
> conceptions of and prejudices against homosexuality onto the text, I suspect that that's not what's
> going on here; Dods is writing in the nineteenth century and probably is trying to be cagey about
> the vice he's referring to. –Roscelese (talk   ⋅contribs) 01:03, 14 April 2014 (UTC)

---

> Roscelese, do you have a reliable source of commentary on Dods that offers that
> explanation or is this your personal opinion? Elizium23 (talk) 02:13, 14 April 2014 (UTC)

---

> Oh, it's my opinion and I'd never suggest that we put it in the article. I initially read
> AlaskaTW's comment as suggesting that we discuss the differences in translation and
> was going to say that we would need an analytical source for that, but then realized
> that s/he just wanted to use the Dods translation instead, which I'm not sure is a good
> idea. Not knowing the original text and only seeing these two translations, I'm
> speculating that Dods's 19th-century translation is just avoiding directness because of
> social taboos. –Roscelese (talk   ⋅contribs) 02:32, 14 April 2014 (UTC)

> :Dods put "filthiness" in his translation where the original has ἀρσενοκοιτἰα.  This is
> an inaccurate translation.  His motive for using the word "filthiness" was doubtless
> that which Roscelese indicated.  I used "filthiness" as my translation of μολυσμός, a
> word very different from ἀρσενοκοιτἰα, and I can show that "filthiness" is an accurate
> translation of μολυσμός, though not of ἀρσενοκοιτἰα.  In another part of the same
> document (chapter II), Dods translated οὐκ εἶ ἀρσενοκοίτης ("you are not an
> ἀρσενοκοίτης", "you are not one who practises ἀρσενοκοιτἰα") as "you do not corrupt
> boys", no doubt in line with what Dods considered the most common form of
> homosexual activity.
> :On a slightly different matter, I must plead guilty to having over-simplified by giving
> "rape" as an English translation of Latin ''stuprum''.  Just go to the Wikipedia
> indication of the meaning of ''[[stuprum]]'', or better to the sources cited there, and
> you will find that the meaning of ''stuprum'' was much wider.  [[User:Esoglou|
> Esoglou]] ([[User talk:Esoglou|talk]]) 14:55, 17 April 2014 (UTC)

Comment: Check the dictionary or lexicons of its meaning, you will find many articles or work online with great detail. The word arsenkoi means homosexual - study this article https://bible.org/article/homosexuality-biblical-christian-view also see askdrbrown Michael Brown's work on this

Comment: @TWFJR I encourage you to sign up here and make an account. I've reached out to a friend who is an expert on this topic, and hopefully he will weigh in at some point in the near future.